# Execute scripts returned from .each() synchronously, but without delay in order of completion

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, each

The situation is that I am dynamically loading a set of scripts from an API that I then call via `eval()`.  I don't care which order the scripts are called, but I don't want any of them to be called at the same time.  That is, scripts A, B, and C can be returned in order C, B, A, and I want to begin `eval(C)` immediately when C is returned, but I want `eval(B)` to wait until `eval(C)` is completed.

Without getting into the fully hairy code, here is the heart of it where "instances" is a string array.

```
$.each(instances, function( index, instance ) {
    var apiUrl = "http://the-api-url.com/" + instance;
    $.getJSON(apiUrl, function(data) {
        // except I don't want to eval here as evaluations may overlap
        eval(data.script);
    });
});
```

From what I understand, I could use `.when()` to wait until all were complete, but that would waste time as I don't need to wait until all are downloaded in order to begin their execution.

Comment: Read about Promises in ES5.

Comment: If you are saying that they can be downloaded and executed in any order, but that the calls to `eval()` cannot "overlap" then you have already written that code.

Comment: Are you eval'ing any async operations? Otherwise i don't see any issue in your logic

Comment: "*I don't want any of them to be called at the same time*" - That's impossible anyway. Events are handled sequentially in JavaScript, there is no way to get them execute in parallel and interfere with each other.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a bit unclear from your question, but assuming that the scripts can be executed in any order (`A, B, C`, `A, C, B`, `B, A, C`, etc.) then you don't have to change anything.

Javascript (in the browser) is single threaded, so the callbacks you are passing to `$.getJSON` will be scheduled serially.

Comment: Added _(in the browser)_ because I believe there are some environments (node?) where you can do things in parallel but I could be wrong about that.

Comment: Even in browser you could run webworkers with some limitations but... I think your answer is enough :)

Comment: Thanks!  This is a relief.